# Error installing cocoapods: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ios, cocoapods

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150610-6663-7exisu.rb extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile

```
make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

This is error log in terminal and i cant find the solution i update
the ruby and system and lots of stuff where i wrong- i have ios7 and
Mac-10.9